# Prove a sequence as 1/k as a cluster point and show

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits-without-lhopital

I'm going through a set of practice problems on my own and I'm stuck on this one:

Let $h(n)$ be the largest prime factor of the integer $n > 1$, and $s(n)$ be the sum of its prime factors, so $h(12) = 3$, $s(12) = 7$.

Prove the sequence $\frac{h(k)}{s(k)}, n = 2, 3, 4, . . .$ has $1/k$ as a cluster point for every positive integer $k$, but no limit.

I think I need to construct a formula for both h(n) and s(n) and then show that 1. $|\frac{h(k)}{s(k)} - \frac{1}{k}| < \varepsilon$ and $\frac{h(k)}{s(k)}$ converges to infinity. However I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: If you *could* construct such formulae you'd be well on your way to factorising arbitrary integers with ease :)  Rather consider that $h(n)/s(n) = h(n)/(h(n)+...)$ to start with, and that whenever $n$ is prime $h(n)=s(n)$

Comment: You recieved an answer to your question. Is it what you needed? If so, consider accepting the answer. That's how the site works. If it is not what you needed, please explain what is still left unclear.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to construct a formula for $h(n)$ and $s(n)$. All you need is to find enough values of $k$ for which $\frac{h(k)}{s(k)}$ is close to $\frac1k$.

To do that, think about when $\frac{h(k)}{s(k)}$ is close to $\frac1k$. That will happen if $s(k)$ is "about $k$ times bigger than $h(k)$". To do that, consider what happens when $k=p\cdot 2^n$ for some prime value $p$ and some integer $n$.

---

Once you prove that each $\frac1k$ is a cluster point of the sequence, it is trivial to argue that the sequence cannot have a limit. You can simply use the fact that convergent sequences, i.e. those with a limit, always have *only one cluster point*.

Comment: So I understand that h(k) = p, s(k) = p + 2n, and when n = (pk-p)/2, h(k)/s(k) = 1/k. The problem now is, how to I prove formally that 1/k is a cluster point for each k?

Comment: @JustinBurack Your calculations are a little bit off. If $n=\frac{pk-p}{2}$, then $\frac{h(k)}{s(k)} = \frac{p}{p+\frac{pk-p}{2}} = \frac{2p}{2p+pk-p} = \frac{2}{2+k-1}\neq k$. But in either case, you *formally* prove that $\frac1k$ is a cluster point by using the definition of what a cluster point is. That is $c$ is a cluster point if, for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exist some element of the sequence $a_k$ such that $|a_k-c|<\epsilon$. Your proof will probably need to start with the famous words "Let $\epsilon > 0$" :)

Comment: @JustinBurack Is anything left unclear?